# Bootstrap button to bottom

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How to place the Scroll button to the bottom of the first page?
Using bootstrap code and not using extra CSS.

[Example site](http://federicomalagoni.it/Bootstrap%20Site/index.html)

This is what I mean:
[image]

Comment: what do you mean bottom of the first page?

Comment: I think this will require extra css.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't think bootstrap has anything built-in for this.

If you want to write some css, consider the following example:

HTML:

```
<div class="outside">
    <div class="inside"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outside {
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #eee;
    position: relative; /* This allows you to position something absolutely within this element. */
}

.inside {
    height: 50px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: #ccc;
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute; /* This allows you to specify the position within the parent element */
    bottom: 10px; /* will be located 10px from the bottom of 'outside' */

    /* This is a method for centering an absolutely positioned element */
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -50px; /* Half of the width, so that it can be centered
}
```

#### [Example fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1pmr7e4g/)

Answer (score 1):

you can use position fixed? that would keep it at the bottom of the page

```
button{
    position:fixed;
    bottom:20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lf5o705a/

or position absolute would keep it at the bottom of the first section

```
button{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lf5o705a/1/